# Frame dependence

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology

I was reading an article about magnetospheres, and came across this quote:

> This supersonic ionized gas, or plasma, called the solar wind carries with it a magnetic field and a frame dependent electric field. The frame-dependence arises due to the high electrical conductivity of the plasma and its magnetic field.

What does 'frame dependent electric field' mean? Does one often talk of frame dependence in relation to electromagnetism, or it this term used generally in context of astronomy?

Comment: Good question: both E and M fields are *always* frame dependent (F transforms as a valence 2 tensor by Lorentz transformations), so it looks as though there is some "jargon" or "in-speak" particular to this area of study not known to you and me. Otherwise it would be tautological phrase, which would be silly.